# Portable headphone amplifier - max output and power supply

Tags: power-supply, amplifier

According to the specs listed on [this page](https://www.jdslabs.com/products/70/c5-headphone-amplifier/), that portable headphone amp can produce different maximum voltage, depending on the impedance of headphones:

> Max Output @ 600Ω 4.146 VRMS
>
> Max Output @ 150Ω 3.580 VRMS
>
> Max Output @ 32Ω  1.182 VRMS

I guess such a big difference in maximum voltage is caused by the fact, that low impedance headphones draw much more current, and higher voltages would exceed the maximum current the amp may provide (with 32 Ohm cans, for example). Is that the reason why max voltages vary that much?

The second thing in the "amplifier performance" column:

> Power Supply  14.0 Vpp

How can a portable amplifier equipped with a 3.7V battery produce 14V? Or maybe it simply means something else.

I'm not saying there's anything wrong in the specs, rather I'd like to know why this may be true (as a beginner in this field).

Comment: "Powered by a large 1200mAh Li-Ion battery" Large compared to a button cell I suppose...

Comment: What are much more important questions are: What kind of portable device (in every sense!!) would generate an audio signal that needs those levels of THD, L/R channel balance, noise or crosstalk? And why would someone interested in those levels ever want as much distortion as is a Bass Boost? And what is the point of specifying 0.1% resistors?

Comment: if you ripped your CD collection to FLAC you might appreciate this performance...

Comment: This is totally off-topic - speak to the supplier or get hold of a circuit diagram and post it - then you'll get plenty of sensible answers.

Answer (score 2):

It looks as if the unit has a bipolar DC-DC boost converter within.  They specifically mention plus minus 7V rails.

Regarding the output voltage maximum specs: my best guess is that they are running into current limitations of their power amp stages.  As far as I am concerned, this is a reasonable trade-off.  Those voltage levels into headphones or In Ear Monitor (IEM) buds will be painfully loud.